# Refresh materialized view. Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tell me how refreshing materialized views works. On the Internet, I read that they update themselves, but I have old data in them.

Can you tell me if there is a possibility to make automatic refreshing of MV every day at 5 am?

If there are several MV, how to make them update one by one?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did not find answers to my questions in this article.

Comment: Schedule a job to refresh the materialized view on the schedule you want.

Answer (score 1):

REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW table_name;

You need to execute this statement to get the data refreshed in the Materialized view. To auto refresh everyday, one way is, you can schedule a cron job in your server that runs everyday at 5am.

If in case your view query is not complex, you can choose to go with simple View instead of Materialized view. In that case your View will be dynamic and you do not have to worry about refreshing the data everyday.